# Take query data to build new table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, view

I have a table I run a query against and get results like:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Account January February March April May June July August September October November December
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1234      0        50     100    0    0    0   120   280    800        0      650      124
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I transform this query to display the data like:

```
------------------------
Account    Period  Amount
-------------------------
1234        Jan      0
1234        Feb      50
1234        Mar      100
.
.
1234        Dec      124
--------------------------
```

Would I create a view, stored proc, or something else? (excuse my lack of knowledge as I am not really a DBA but need to find a solution to assist with this.)

Comment: Usually it's helpful if you specify which database you're using. And its version.  There are many ways to skin this cat!

Comment: Related: [Desired output with given table data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408622/desired-output-with-given-table-data). Although Oracle-dpecific, one of the offered methods of solving the problems of this kind (the method of cross-joining to a virtual table) is likely applicable in the majority of SQL products.

Answer (score 1):

Your could display it with a query something like:

```
SELECT Account, 'Jan' as Period, January as Amount
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

SELECT Account, 'Feb' as Period, February as Amount
FROM myTable

UNION ALL

...
```

Comment: +1 since this works for all rdbms ,but if rdbms is oracle 11g ,use the solution mentioned by Mickeal.

Comment: How will this work if all of the data is in a single table? Isn't the union all operator for joining data from multiple tables?

Comment: @rspencer - `UNION ALL` works to combine results from multiple queries, no matter where those queries come from. Yes, this works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use unpivot if that is supported in the DBMS you use.

Something like this:

```
select U.Account, 
       U.Period,
       U.Amount
from 
  ( -- Your query goes here
    select 
      1234 as Account,
      0 as Januar,
      50 as February,
      100 as March
  ) as T
unpivot
  (
    Amount for Period in (Januar, February, March)
  ) as U
```

Result:

```
Account     Period     Amount
----------- ---------- -----------
1234        Januar     0
1234        February   50
1234        March      100
```

Comment: i think this is only in oracle 11g ,have to search if the person is asking for different rdbms ,but surely +1 for giving the concept of unpivot.

Comment: @GauravSoni - Works in SQL Server from 2005 as well.

Comment: How well will that work when there are over 6000 rows in the orginal query?

Comment: @rspencer - Just tested on a really sad laptop and it took 2 seconds to upivot 6000 rows into 72000 rows. Only you can tell if that is good enough for you.

Comment: @Mikael I did get the unpivot to work thanks for the help. The first time I read your post I misunderstood and thought you were stating I needed to put the actual amount values in the imbedded delect statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think the above answer of unpivot is probably best if your db supports it but... i have a feeling your original query can be modified accomplish this with a simple "group by"

```
select ..
from <table>
where Account = '1234'
group by Account, Period
```

Comment: not possible sam ,you are confusing query result with table columns

Comment: you're just assuming he's doing "select *" from this aggregated table.  i'm just leaving the possibility open in case he's doing the aggregation in the "query"... and no, i'm not confusing query result with table columns. =)