# SQL query Convert column to row

Tags: sql

My table has the following columns:

```
roll no | subject1 | subject2 | subject3 | subject4 | subject5 | subject6
   1    |    10    |    12    |    13    |    9     |    15    |    16
   2    |    12    |    14    |    10    |    16    |    19    |    13
   3    |    10    |    12    |    13    |    18    |    12    |    15
   4    |    14    |    12    |    13    |    7     |    11    |    17
```

Now i need data in this format:

```
Roll no | SubjectName | Marks
    1   |  subject1   |  10     
    1   |  subject2   |  12     
    1   |  subject3   |  13     
    1   |  subject4   |  9     
    1   |  subject5   |  15     
    1   |  subject6   |  16     
    2   |  subject1   |  12     
    2   |  subject2   |  14     
    2   |  subject3   |  10     
    2   |  subject4   |  16     
    2   |  subject5   |  19     
    2   |  subject6   |  13   
    3   |  subject1   |  10     
    3   |  subject2   |  12     
    3   |  subject3   |  13     
    3   |  subject4   |  18     
    3   |  subject5   |  12     
    3   |  subject6   |  15  
    4   |  subject1   |  14     
    4   |  subject2   |  12     
    4   |  subject3   |  13     
    4   |  subject4   |  7     
    4   |  subject5   |  11     
    4   |  subject6   |  17
```

As you can see i want to display the columns as rows

Thanks

Comment: phpMyadmin 3.4, database is mysql

Comment: @swathhi: Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support `UNPIVOT`, so you'll probably have to use the `UNION ALL` approach.

Comment: Or you can use a cross join to an inline view, like in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408622/desired-output-with-given-table-data/9428760#9428760).

Answer (score 5):

If your database supports [UNPIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx), you can use that.

If not, you can use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT roll_no, 'subject1' AS SubjectName, subject1 AS Marks FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT roll_no, 'subject2', subject2 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT roll_no, 'subject3', subject3 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT roll_no, 'subject4', subject4 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT roll_no, 'subject5', subject5 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT roll_no, 'subject6', subject6 FROM yourtable
UNION ALL
SELECT roll_no, 'subject7', subject7 FROM yourtable
```

Comment: You might want to add "where subject1 is not null" in the event that you have NULLs in the values and don't want to see them in the pivoted results.